# Built-in Trackpad on Macbook Pro broken/behaving erratically

Tags: battery, macbook, touchpad

The trackpad on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid-2015) stopped working a few days ago. The trackpad is still able to click, scroll, and  move around on its sides and corners, but is unresponsive to anything except clicking in the center.

So far, I have tried:

- Restarting the computer.
- Cleaning the trackpad.
- Booting into safe mode.
- Resetting the System Management Controller.
- Resetting its NVRAM and PRAM.
- Changing various mouse and keyboard settings.

I have been using Bootcamp to dual boot Windows 10. The problem persists on the Windows 10 partition of the computer.

I am pretty sure this is a hardware problem, but I am not sure what to replace. I have read about battery swelling on MacBook Pros and my computer does has poor battery life.

Comment: You might be best off using a mouse or external graphics table; Apple products do not seem to be readily repairable. However, see https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Battery+and+Trackpad.+Disassembling+MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+2012+2013+2014+2015/51846

Comment: You can visually inspect for battery swelling. By the time you get the machine apart that far you would also have removed the pressure on the back of the top assembly, so the trackpad ought to work again... Once confirmed, change the battery.